# Join with importrange and Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I Need a query that returns
Sheet_1

```
A | B | C 
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
```

Sheet_2

```
D | E | F | G | H | I | 
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 |
2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

Join results

```
A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
4 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 |
  |   |   | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
  |   |   | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
  |   |   | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
  |   |   | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
  |   |   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

It's possible with `query` and `importrange` in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({Sheet_1!A1:C100, Sheet_2!D1:I100}, "where Col4 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

---

## UPDATE:

in your case, you will need 3 types of formulae because your dataset is not uniform enough. therefore, create a new spreadsheet and import (with `IMPORTRANGE` formula) all markets in separate sheets:

[image: 0]

then create a MASTER sheet in which you will join all data from all markets

in **A1** cell paste:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({market1!A1:J2, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 market1!K1:2, market2!K1:2}), "where Col2 is not null", 0))})
```

[image: 0]

---

in **A3** cell paste:

```
=QUERY({market1!A3:J; market2!A3:J}, "where Col2 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

and then paste this into **K3** cell and drag it to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B3:$B, QUERY({
 market1!$B3:$B, IFERROR(INDIRECT("market1!"&ADDRESS(3, MATCH(K1, market1!$A1:1, 0), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(market1!$A:$A), MATCH(K1, market1!$A1:1, 0), 4)), REGEXREPLACE(market1!$B3:$B,".*",));
 market2!$B3:$B, IFERROR(INDIRECT("market2!"&ADDRESS(3, MATCH(K1, market2!$A1:1, 0), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(market2!$A:$A), MATCH(K1, market2!$A1:1, 0), 4)), REGEXREPLACE(market2!$B3:$B,".*",))},
 "where Col1 is not null", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Is part of the “technique” in this answer, the placement of the second range commencing in columnD, so that it is adjacent to the first range? I ask because a dolt like me would have assumed the second range was also in column A, and spent the day try to join two ranges that each contained “ColA, ColB, and ColC”.

Comment: not at all. if your data in sheet2 starts from column A you can have `=QUERY({Sheet_1!A1:C100, Sheet_2!A1:F100}, "where Col4 is not null", 0)`

Comment: I try but return err. see...
=QUERY(
  {
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:BG" );
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:P);
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:T");
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AA");
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:O");
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AK");
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AF);
    IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AO")

  };

  "WHERE Col5 IS NOT NULL"
)

Comment: Like? Sorry i am not speak English... i have difficulty in write right... Help me, please!!!

Comment: try: `=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:BG100")\
        IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:P100")\ 
        IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:T100")\ 
        IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AA100")\ 
        IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:O100")\
        IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AK100")\ 
        IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AF100")\ 
        IMPORTRANGE("Id"; "Analyses by Types!K6:AO100")}; "WHERE Col5 IS NOT NULL", 0)`